# Autowired property is null in EnvironmentPostProcessor implementation class on startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, spring-context

In my SpringBoot app, I have Autowired an `configObject` in the class that implements `EnvironmentPostProcessor`.

The injected class reads data from a different source on startup as this is required for the app to work.

But upon starting the application, the `configObject` is coming off as Null.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableCaching
@Slf4j
public class SBApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SBApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the AppEnvironmentPostProcessor class where the Autowired object is called. This class is configured as `org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor` in spring.factories. The class gets called on start up.

```java
@Slf4j
public class AppEnvironmentPostProcessor implements
        EnvironmentPostProcessor, Ordered {

    @Autowired
    KeysConfig keysConfig;

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
                                       SpringApplication application) {
        // keysConfig is null
        String key = keysConfig.getSecretKeyMap().get("key12");
    }
}
```

And in the KeysConfig class

```java
@Component
public final class KeysConfig {
    public Map getSecretKeyMap() {
        //Returns key map
    }
}
```

I am using Intellij Ultimate. How can I debug and resolve this?

Comment: Without seeing the Configuration code where you declare the Bean and the Controller, it's impossible to say.

Comment: not to mention without seeing any of your code. How do you initialize your class?

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry about that. Question updated.

Comment: @continuousLearner you should know enough about java to understand that none of that tells us enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EnvironmentPostProcessor`s are created before the application context has been created and, therefore, before dependency injection is possible. This means that `@Autowired` won’t work.

You’ll have to update your implementation to create an instance of `KeysConfig` itself, or to use a different approach that mimics whatever `KeysConfig` currently does.